# How to login users that are stored within a Wordpress account

Tags: sql, objective-c, wordpress, ios7, xcode5

I am developing an iOS app that is password protected and all the users are stored in a wordpress account that, of course, is password protected as well. Does anybody know the format that wordpress uses to store login information for these accounts, I would assume that it is a MySQL that sends a json? I have only been able to find the database code for the initial admin page but nothing that shows the way these accounts (815 to be exact) would be stored within the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw data is in the `wp_users` MySQL table.

The (default) code WordPress to authenticate users in the [`wp_check_password`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1839) function.  It's possible (though unlikely) that the password is a straight MD5 hash (I assume that check's just for backwards compatibility).  Usually, it'll be encrypted using the [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library (see here for the [WordPress code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php)).

As far as I know, there's no API for checking a password that returns JSON.  You'd probably have to write something yourself.  [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61353/how-to-check-username-password-without-signing-in-the-user) suggests the `wp_authenticate_username_password` would be the best way to check the username / password combination on the server.